# Eventbrite RSS feed not validate, general events feed not my events

Tags: rss, eventbrite

I was hoping to integrate an eventbrite RSS feed into my site, this is not my event instead these are general events for my geographic area.

Link of the page

https://www.eventbrite.com/d/ca--sacramento/business--events/?crt=regular&page=1&radius=96.5606400369&sort=best

When I choose the link for the feed I get the event titles but the excerpt and body content is not working.  I do have an API but I am not quite sure how to integrate it I think the API only works for events that I have created or organized. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do or does something like this require special authorization from eventrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Event Search endpoint](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-search) in the Eventbrite API to do the same thing as the RSS feed. All you need to do is enter the parameters you wish to use such as 'venue.city', 'categories', etc.

Also, you don't need authentication if the events are public (Which all the events returned here are).